# How to update a List of entities in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-update

I have a list of objects I'm trying to update in the database. I can update one of them like so

```
MyObj entity = getObjectFromDb();
entity.changeSomething();
getHibernateTemplate().update(entity);
```

What if I have a List of objects? Is it possible to do this without iterating through the list of objects and updating them one by one? That doesn't sound efficient to me. So I need something like this

```
List<MyObj> entities = getObjectsFromDb();
//change some attribute of the entities
getHibernateTemplate().update(entities); //this doesn't work because entities is a List
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of a hibernate specific method that would take multiple objects (that doesn't mean it doesn't exist).  EDIT -> [Updating a collection does exist!](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#saveOrUpdateAll(java.util.Collection)) 
I would imagine that it is simply iterating through them one by one and executing 1 query per object.  A few options for you would be (in order of what I think would be best/most performant):

- You could write a [Bulk HQL Update](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-bulk) update statement.
- You could write a raw SQL update statement.
- You could write your own helper object that takes multiple objects and saves them
- You could rely on Hibernate's dirty/flush logic to save the objects that have changed and developers for all of time will curse you.

Comment: I would still suggest doing a single HQL query for performance reasons because you will be executing N number of queries against your database.  But that's just my 2 cents.